# How to change the icon of published c# app

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, clickonce

I published my wpf app, but I get this icon:

[image]

How do I replace this icon, and also the setup name from visual studio?

I tried: right click on the project--> properties--> application-->icon and manifest-->and browsed to my icon.

but this changed only the icon on top of the window, like:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by setup name?

Comment: I mean instead that visual studio would create `setup.exe` I want it to generate `MyApp.exe`

Comment: What about simply renaming setup.exe to MyApp.exe once it is generated?

Comment: @MatějŠtágl And every time that I fix a bug I would need to change the name again? That's a crooked way to do this.

Comment: You are not deploying to production on eaćh bugfix, right?

Comment: First off all, there's a difference between publish and build. Use your own setup application or create one from many available providers. This will let you choose icon, name and even STEPS! This question is basically you not understanding how software deployment/publishing works and not a programming related topic.

Comment: *"This will let you choose icon, name and even STEPS!"* Really? then tell me **How**. I'm using only visual studio, not Installshield @Mateusz

Comment: Flufy watch your tone, before this gets closed

Comment: @Flufy Since you've heard about InstallShield you can use it or google some similar install wizard projects. For the future reference: this site's main purpose is to ask programming related questions. Yours is not, you should find adequate StackExchange site to ask this kind of question

Comment: I'm using [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx), that's another way to deploy app, there is no reason to go to some other install wizard. I'm sure that there is solution via visual studio

Comment: @Flufy `setup.exe` is the *installer*, not your application's executable. You don't need to and *should not* try to rename it. You need to set the name and icon for your executable, just like you'd do for any Winforms or WPF application. The options for that are in the main project's property pages

Comment: `Really? then tell me How.` the answer to that would be "look at the docs, it's all there". You seem to misunderstand what ClickOnce is - it's *not* a general-purpose installer, it's meant for *intra*net scenarios. General puprose installers can be created eg using the [Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) extension. This can generate an msi package with or without a `setup.exe` bootstraper

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So if I will create 100 different apps, all of the would have the same `setup.exe` name?

Comment: @Flufy you confuse the application with its **setup bootstrapper**. The *bootstrapper* can only exist alongside the application's setup files.

Comment: ClickOnce is not very customizable. You can change the icon of setup.exe *after* the application has been pubished: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019832/how-to-change-setup-exe-icon-when-publishing-through-clickonce

Comment: @Flufy your application is called `WpfApplication.application`, not `setup.exe`. It's `WpfApplication.application` that runs, checks the source for updates, performs the update if necessary or keeps running otherwise. Perhaps you should explain what kind of application you want to deploy? ClickOnce makes sense for simplified enterprise deployments. If you have a lot of small apps, use UWP and the Windows App Store. Generic applications need installers like those created by the Visual Studio Installer projecs, Installshield etc.

Comment: @mm8 Yes, the second answer there worked for me, can you see how it's possible to rename the app via visual studio?

Comment: "The app"? What file do you want to rename?

Comment: @mm8 I mean that instead of `setup.exe` name, I want that visual would generate `MyAppSetup.exe`

Comment: @Flufy: VS won't let you do this. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid ClickOnce is not very customizable. You can change the icon of setup.exe *after* the application has been published as suggested by @Equalsk here:

[How to change Setup.exe icon when publishing through clickonce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019832/how-to-change-setup-exe-icon-when-publishing-through-clickonce)

Then you can also change the name of the file:

[How to rename setup file in ClickOnce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952916/how-to-rename-setup-file-in-clickonce)